# Why do I get an empty response from fetch call?

Tags: javascript, azure, fetch

I have Azure function app written in python. App works in azure editor fine and in calling request from python also fine. But when I want to call it from  client side javascript (from my react app) I get empty response

I call it in this way:

```
    fetch("https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/testtrigger?", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => response.text()).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
```

The no-cors is there because I test it on localhost.

Function code looks like this:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Function called')
    return func.HttpResponse("Its working")
```

Azure shows that function is being called, but is there any reason I missed why this should't work? I receive response but its empty, here is response json:

```
     Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers[[Prototype]]: Headersappend: ƒ append()delete: ƒ delete()entries: ƒ entries()forEach: ƒ forEach()get: ƒ ()has: ƒ has()keys: ƒ keys()set: ƒ ()values: ƒ values()constructor: ƒ Headers()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Headers"[[Prototype]]: Objectok: falseredirected: falsestatus: 0statusText: ""type: "opaque"url: ""[[Prototype]]: Response
```

**This code in python works fine:**

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/testtrigger')
print(x.text)
```

Comment: Is it erroring? What happens if you add a catch block? Does the console.log run at all?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, there is no error log, but guy below explained why its not working.

Comment: In fact, you really need to do that for [all your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9616340/erik-palen%c4%8d%c3%adk#). worth noting that you get rep too if you accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no-cors` is an explicit directive to `fetch` to tell it not to do anything that requires the server to use CORS to grant permission.

Reading the response body requires permission.

Since you said `no-cors` you get an empty body instead of the data the server responded with.

Comment: So the only way how to test my static web application  with function app is to put in online on same origin as function app?

Comment: No. You can enable CORS, use a development server instead of a production server, or use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

So bassicaly answer for this is - **I can't** call azure functions from  client side browser on local host, I have to add to my package.json:

```
  "proxy": "https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
```

and fetch in with:

```
fetch("/api/testtrigger")
```